# onSignalStrengthChanged Android - how to retrieve the value from the callback

Tags: java, android, callback, signal-strength

I am developing an Android app that reads the signal strength and store it on a local database. However, I can read the signal strength and write it on the TextView but I can't store the value. Does anybody know how to retrieve a value from onSignalStrengthChanged callback?

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of this out there. The change event returns an object that can be used to get data you are interested in, and there are a few to choose from. Here is a sample:

```
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        int levelValue = signalStrength.getLevel();
        int evdoSnrValue = signalStrength.getEvdoSnr();
        //Here you would store the "levelValue" and "evdoSnrValue" in your database.
}
```

Here are the rest of the methods available:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html